# Can't create a numbered list with jquery using OL

Tags: jquery, html, list, html-lists

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/chc9N/12/

Specifically I have list tags which are added to this:

```
<ol type="1"></ol>
```

Based on my reading this should create numebred lists like this:

1. Test
2. Test
3. Test

However it just creates normal bullet points as if the UL tag was used. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: They are wrapped in ol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ol reference is wrong, you are adding the `li`s to `div#preview` instead of the `ol` element

```
var list = $('#testy');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WKGUY/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = $('#preview');
```

This should be

```
var list = $("#preview > ol");
//or
var list = $("#testy");
```

At some point you  use `list.empty()` which removes the `<ol>`.  Then you probably wouldn't need the `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

check this

use this

```
var list = $('#testy');
```

instead of

```
var list = $('#preview');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chc9N/13/